# Upload a picture to cloudinary using the REST API

Tags: actionscript-3, air, cloudinary, urlrequest, as3crypto

We are developing an App using AIR/AS3 and would like to upload a picture to cloudinary via the REST API from the client, instead of using Node.js.

Reading the Documentation of cloudinary, we have found that it should be done via a HTTP/S POST request (http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#remote_upload).

We've tried using a URLLoader and URLRequest passing the parameters as URLVariables.

Using this as a URL: 
`'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/'+ CLOUD_NAME +'/raw/upload'`

The code looks like this:

```
public function uploadImage(imageVO:CameraUIImageVO):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_url);

    request.data = getVariables(imageVO);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    loader.load(request);
}

private function getVariables(imageVO:CameraUIImageVO):URLVariables {
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.timestamp = _timestamp;

    var bitmapData:BitmapData = imageVO.image.bitmapData;
    var rawBytes:ByteArray = bitmapData.encode(bitmapData.rect, new JPEGEncoderOptions(50));
    variables.file = rawBytes;
    variables.resource_type = 'raw';

    variables.signature = getSignature("anyPublicId");
    variables.api_key = API_KEY;

    return variables;
}

private function getSignature(publicId:String):String {
    var toHash:String =
            "public_id="+ publicId
            + "&timestamp=" + timestamp
            + API_SECRET;

    var src:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(toHash));
    var sha1:SHA1 = new SHA1();
    var hashedString:String = Hex.fromArray(sha1.hash( src ));

    return hashedString;
}


private function get timestamp():String {
    return _timestamp = Number(new Date().time).toString();
}
```

The result of this is a http error 401

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're signing the `public_id`, however the `public_id` isn't passed in options of the upload itself. i.e., there's no:

```
variables.public_id = "anyPublicId";
```

inside the `getVariables` method.